# Debian/Armbian: mediainfo exits with code 1 on .mkv files

Tags: linux, debian, video, matroska, armbian

I hope superuser.com is the right spot for this kind of issues.

**Status quo:**

Today i updated my BananaPi M1 to Debian Stretch (Armbian) and installed all packages I need from the plain Strech repo, no dev stuff or the like. The setup also includes `mediainfo` which I need for certain media center scripts.

**My problem:**

Running mediainfo on audio files, subtitles or whatever comes to my mind works as expected. Video files like .mp4 or .avi work as well but when I throw a .mkv file at mediainfo it just quits with an exit code of 1 and that's it. No error message, no nothing.

I had mediainfo running for years before without any problems or hiccups, but I wasn't feeling safe on an outdated Raspbian Wheezy, hence the upgrade.
Can anyone tell me what's going on there with mediainfo? Are there certain interdependencies which I don't know of? Something very special with .mkv files?

I cannot recall performing any magic stuff in order to make mediainfo work when I set it up back then on Wheezy.

Any help is highly appreciated!

---

**EDIT:**

For testing purposes I installed the current version of `mediainfo` on my Windows PC and checked a few files. Here I'll post the `Writing application` and `Writing library` fields from mediainfo's output and note, whether I get the same output on my Linux machine:

*File 1* (working):

```
Writing application     : mkvmerge v6.1.0 ('Old Devil') built on Mar  2 2013 14:32:37
Writing library         : libebml v1.3.0 + libmatroska v1.4.0
```

*File 2* (not working):

```
Writing application     : mkvmerge v4.8.0 ('I Got The...') built on May 23 2011 22:50:52
Writing library         : libebml v1.2.0 + libmatroska v1.1.0
```

*File 3* (not working):

```
Writing application     : mkvmerge v17.0.0 ('Be Ur Friend') 64-bit
Writing library         : libebml v1.3.5 + libmatroska v1.4.8
```

*File 4* (not working):

```
Writing application     : mkvmerge v9.2.0 ('Photograph') 64bit
Writing library         : libebml v1.3.3 + libmatroska v1.4.4
```

*File 5* (working):

```
Writing application     : mkvmerge v8.3.0 ('Over the Horizon') 64bit
Writing library         : libebml v1.3.1 + libmatroska v1.4.2
```

I can't deduct any consistent behaviour from these outputs. Any ideas on this? Does this help at all?

Comment: What version of `mediainfo` are you using?

Comment: I'm using 0.7.91

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it now by installing other versions of two libraries which `mediainfo` depends on, namely `libmediainfo` and `libzen`. Since I'm on Debian 9 (Stretch) I had to add the Jessie repo to my apt/sources.list as well in order to install older versions.

In doing this I replaced the libraries as follows:

```
libmediainfo0v5    ->    libmediainfo0
libzen0v5          ->    libzen0
```

I now have mediainfo 0.7.70 with the above mentioned libraries installed and it works.